# Is there a name for the norm $||\mathbf{x}||_{W}^{2}=\mathbf{x}^{T}W^{T}W\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: normed-spaces, noise

I'm in the process of reading [this paper](http://www.dbabacan.info/papers/Campisi_Egiazarian_BIDmain_FOR_CH1.pdf), and I came across a peculiar *weighted* norm (as the authors describe it) on [page 7](http://www.dbabacan.info/papers/Campisi_Egiazarian_BIDmain_FOR_CH1.pdf#page=15),

\begin{align}
||\mathbf{x}||_{W}^{2}=\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}W^{\text{T}}W\mathbf{x}
\end{align}

but I'm having trouble finding information about by Googling and on this site. Has anyone come across it, or could someone point me toward a resource where I might learn more about it?

I'm only asking because it looks *similar* to the simpler Mahalanobis distance metric, and the authors use it in a similar way, i.e. modeling the probability of observation noise.

Comment: It is an interesting fact that every inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written in the form $\langle x, y \rangle := x^T M x$ for some symmetric positive definite matrix $M$. Similarly, every symmetric positive definite matrix $M$ defines an inner product via the above formula. Furthermore, every symmetric positive definite matrix $M$ can be factorized to the form $M=W^TW$ for some matrix $W$ (e.g. the Cholesky factorization), and every matrix of the form $W^TW$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. So, basically, this is just a statement that the norm comes from an inner product.

Comment: @NickAlger thanks! You reduced this brilliantly

Comment: also we have the "matrix norm" terminology, which applies as:
$$<x,y>_A=x^TA^TAy.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this may be helpful but note that
$$\mathbf{x}^TW^T W\mathbf{x} =(W\mathbf{x)}^TW\mathbf{x} \color{red}{=} (W\mathbf{x}) \cdot (W\mathbf{x}) = ||W\mathbf{x}||^2$$

where we treat the vector with only one component as a scalar (red equals sign).

Comment: Nice work; it's been a while since I reviewed my linear algebra, I hope to get back into this at some point. Thanks!

Comment: @jm324354 Thanks. It was an interesting question. So basically this new metric is just the standard metric that is "weighted" by multiplication of a matrix. For example, if $W = 3I$, then the norm would increase by a factor of $3^2$.